# MySQL over SSL with self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, cryptography, certificate, mysql

I'm setting up a mysql server and am trying to have a mysql client connect to it over SSL. I'm going to be using a self signed certificate for the same. Reading the MySQL documentation on setting up SSL I see that I have to specify the path to the following files :-

```
the SSL root CA
the SSL certificate
the SSL private key
```

In this particular case, should I be setting both the root CA and the certificate to my self signed certificate?

Comment: I would call that extremely likely, yes. Maybe you can get away by specifying only one of the two certificate files, but I think you would normally be OK when specifying both (the client needs to trust this self signed certificate of course).

Comment: Note that these kind of questions are rather off topic here, they are better asked at serverfault...

Answer (score -3):

*Example of how to create properly a Self-Signed SSL Certificate.*

**Su to root and create a directory that only the root account has access to.**

```
su -

mkdir certificates

chmod 700 certificates

cd certificates
```

**Use openssl to generate a server key**

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 4096
```

**Openssl will request a pass phrase. Type in a sentence that is long and complex but that you can remember (you'll have to type it at least twice). Try to make it at least 40 characters long, with punctuation and capital and lowercase letters. The more different characters you use the better.
Then create the certificate signing request with the server key you created in step 2.**

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

**Sign your certificate using SSL.**

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

**You can set your certificate for any number of days, but I recommend 365 so that you remember to update it once a year.**

**Once you're done, you'll have the following files:**

```
server.crt: The self-signed server certificate
server.csr: Server certificate signing request
server.key: The private server key, does not require a password when starting Apache
```

**Place those files where they are required for your Web server, and turn on HTTPS. (If you don't know how, contact your server administrator.)**

Comment: This question is about MySQL not Apache HTTPD.